# How to print all information from an HTTP request to the screen, in PHP

Tags: php, http

I need some PHP code that does a dump of all the information in an HTTP request, including headers and the contents of any information included in a POST request. Basically, a diagnostic tool that spits out exactly what I send to a server.

Does anyone have some code that does this?

Comment: Nowadays both Chrome and Firefox let you easily view network traffic (including headers for requests and responses) in their in-browser [developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#http-headers).  No need to fiddle with printing headers manually in PHP.

Comment: @dimo414, there are cases where what reaches the server is different from what the browser sends, e.g. when the connection goes through proxies or CDNs...

Comment: Yes. And there are cases where you send a request from a C# application rather than a browser.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To get [$_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php):

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

---

If you want the headers:

```
print_r(apache_request_headers());
```

Comment: I think the op wanted HEADERS. This, by the doc is `associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE`. So for a simple `GET` request, it's empty.

Comment: Doesn't provide headers.

Answer (score 38):

Well, you can read the entirety of the POST body [like so](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

```
echo file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
```

And, assuming your webserver is Apache, you can read the request headers [like so](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)

```
$requestHeaders = apache_request_headers();
```

Comment: best among all (y)

Comment: `apache_request_headers()`, works also for Php's built in server.  Despite the name.  It has an alias `getallheaders()`

Answer (score 33):

A simple way would be:

```
<?php
print_r($_SERVER);
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

A bit of massaging would be required to get everything in the order you want, and to exclude the variables you are not interested in, but should give you a start.

Comment: Headers are in `$_SERVER`.  Basic pretty print : `foreach($_SERVER as $key => $val) echo($key . "=>" . $val . "<br/>";`.

Answer (score 19):

Nobody mentioned how to dump HTTP headers correctly under any circumstances.

> From CGI specification rfc3875, section 4.1.18:
>
> Meta-variables with names beginning with "HTTP_" contain values read
>   from the client request header fields, if the protocol used is HTTP.
>   The HTTP header field name is converted to upper case, has all
>   occurrences of "-" replaced with "*" and has "HTTP*" prepended to give
>   the meta-variable name.

```
foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'HTTP_') === 0) {
        $chunks = explode('_', $key);
        $header = '';
        for ($i = 1; $y = sizeof($chunks) - 1, $i < $y; $i++) {
            $header .= ucfirst(strtolower($chunks[$i])).'-';
        }
        $header .= ucfirst(strtolower($chunks[$i])).': '.$value;
        echo $header.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Details: http://cmyker.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-dump-http-headers-with-php.html

Comment: Care to comment why are you proposing this? Maybe adding some code from yourself? The link redirects to "How to dump http request headers with PHP under CGI/FastCGI SAPI", are you sure the OP asked for CGI/FastCGI SAPI?

Comment: Because nobody correctly suggested how to dump HTTP headers with PHP.

Comment: I needed to dump http headers in my script. I read this topic, but none of the answers above were helpful and i found solution myself. Now i'm sharing this information to other people. What's wrong?

Comment: Yaroslav, the question was how to do it in PHP, and other answers given worked only in a selection of PHP server APIs. The question was not "how to dump headers in mod_php".

Answer (score 9):

Putting together answers from [Peter Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136304/425738) and [Cmyker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12724450/425738) you get something like:

```
<?php
foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'HTTP_') === 0) {
        $chunks = explode('_', $key);
        $header = '';
        for ($i = 1; $y = sizeof($chunks) - 1, $i < $y; $i++) {
            $header .= ucfirst(strtolower($chunks[$i])).'-';
        }
        $header .= ucfirst(strtolower($chunks[$i])).': '.$value;
        echo $header."\n";
    }
}
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
if ($body != '') {
  print("\n$body\n\n");
}
?>
```

which works with the `php -S` built-in webserver, which is quite a handy feature of PHP.

Answer (score 3):

If you want actual HTTP Headers (both request and response), give [hurl.it](http://hurl.it/) a try.

You can use the PHP command [`apache_request_headers()`](http://php.net/apache_request_headers) to get the request headers and [`apache_response_headers()`](http://php.net/apache_response_headers) to get the current response headers. Note that response can be changed later in the PHP script as long as content has not been served.

Comment: This SO answer has a list of tools like hurl.it : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12637452/363573

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents('php://input')` will not always work.

I have a request with in the headers `content-length=735` and `php://input` is empty string. So depends on how good/valid the HTTP request is.

Comment: I have the same issue when using POSTMAN, so for regular request I just use $_REQUEST or $_POST/$_GET...

Answer (score 0):

in addition, you can use [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php). it doesn't depend on apache..

```
print_r(get_headers());
```

Comment: get_headers() is for getting the headers of another URL, not for the current request.