# php mail function not sending email to gmail account only

Tags: php, email

i am facing a weird problem in my php script. i have made a function to send email and calling the function in my php page. the function works fine when i send mail to yahoo or any other domain but fails when it comes to send mail to the gmail account.below is my code

```
function send_mail($p_to , $p_sub, $p_body)

{

$from = 'xxx@mydomain.com';
$to = $p_to; 
$email_subject = $p_sub;
$email_body = $p_body;

$xheaders = "";
$xheaders .= "From: <$from>\n";
$xheaders .= "X-Sender: <$from>\n";
$xheaders .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n"; // mailer
$xheaders .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; //1 Urgent Message, 3 Normal
$xheaders .= "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$xheaders);

}
```

// 
when i send mail directly to a gmail account for example if a create a new page with the above code by taking hardcoded values for all the fields($p_to,$p_subject,$p_body) and sends mail then it works .

it was working fine earlier and sending mails to gmail account but, somehow stopped working for gmail.i checked the spam bucket also but found nothing.
any idea frnds ???

Comment: It might be [grey-listed](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/180063?hl=en). For unverified domains, Gmail sometimes rejects incoming e-mail to see if the domain will try resending.

Comment: but i am able to send the mail using hardcoded values. and how can i check to see its grey listed or not ?

Comment: It seems there is an issue with the actual values of your variables? ($p_to, $p_sub and $p_body) ?

Comment: one doubt : do i need to use utf-8 charset or it does not matter to use either of them ?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld : checked the values by echoing ... getting correct values.

Comment: In what way do you hardcode them? Do you assign the variables first (like $p_to = 'whoever@gmail.com') or type values directly in the mail() - function?

Comment: i assign the values to the variables only like $p_to ='smone@gmail.com'

Answer (score 0):

Google marks all not verified domains as blacklisted, so your email will be directly moved to the spam box of the gmail user. I think the only thing you can do is to send a mail to the customer service of google and ask if they can verify your domain as safe, but only if you find it really important that gmail users get it in their inbox and not in their spam box.

Comment: but i also checked the spam box and i did not see the mail over there too.. !!

Comment: that's strange, maybe they completely block your domain or ip for some reason, maybe you should ask google's customer service for an answer...

Comment: below code worked. i just checked and got mail in my gmail acct                                                        <?php

$from = 'admin@myhost.com';
$msg ='test';
$subject = 'test';
$to = 'mygmailacct@gmail.com';

$xheaders = "";
    $xheaders .= "From: <$from>\n";
    $xheaders .= "X-Sender: <$from>\n";
    $xheaders .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n"; // mailer
    $xheaders .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; //1 Urgent Message, 3 Normal
    $xheaders .= "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
   

    //.......

    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $xheaders);
echo 'sent';
?>

Comment: please note i written above code on a new page which sends mail on page refresh !!

Comment: this is the issue i am facing . when am putting the same code on a new page and sending mail on page refresh i succeed but when i am calling the same code through a function call i fail only for gmail accounts...!!

Comment: That's weird actually. can u log the php output and send us the answer?

Comment: if i am not wrong every command we run is logged in php.log file... i need to check with my host where the file is or i need to do it myself only ??

Comment: well yes, but most hosts will not give you the php.log file, but you can make a log of all your requests yourself.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136253/how-to-print-all-information-from-an-http-request-to-the-screen-in-php

Answer (score -1):

problem was sorted out. server side modification needed.

Thanks for your replies guys :)

Comment: he had described the problem and solution in comments to the below answer.