# Httppost returning html instead Json code

Tags: php, android, json

here i´m in my first post.
I´m getting started to android.

I trying to connect my app to a webservice throu a tutorial from mybringback, but i´m getting an error with my json return.

```
09-12 15:54:06.717: E/JSON Parser fallha(8254): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

I already found the reason, it´s happen becouse It´s returning the HTML from my php page instead json. When i tried set a fix string with my json it worked.

When i try to get the json from the browser it works fine.

I set a Log.d in the reader and i got this:

```
09-12 15:35:10.807: D/Acha Erro POR FAVOR(6691):        <h1>Login</h1> 
09-12 15:35:10.807: D/Acha Erro(6691):      <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
09-12 15:35:10.807: D/Acha Erro(6691):          Username:<br /> 
09-12 15:35:10.807: D/Acha Erro(6691):          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
09-12 15:35:10.807: D/Acha Erro(6691):          <br /><br /> 
09-12 15:35:10.807: D/Acha Erro(6691):          Password:<br /> 
09-12 15:35:10.807: D/Acha Erro(6691):          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 
09-12 15:35:10.807: D/Acha Erro(6691):          <br /><br /> 
09-12 15:35:10.807: D/Acha Erro(6691):          <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
09-12 15:35:10.807: D/Acha Erro(6691):      </form> 
09-12 15:35:10.807: D/Acha Erro(6691):      <a href="register.php">Register</a>
```

I´ve spent about 3 days trying to find out a way to solve that.

Following my two classes and php

```
package com.example.testemysql;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

     // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //php login script location:

    //localhost :  
    //testing on your device
    //put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    //or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
   // private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/login.php";

    //testing on Emulator:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.bazarsol.6te.net/ANDROID/login.php";

  //testing from a real server:
    //private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/login.php";

    //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //setup input fields
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        //setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

        //register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();   
            break;
        case R.id.register:
                //Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
                //startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

         /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));


                Log.d("URL",LOGIN_URL);
               Log.d("PARAMETROS",""+ params);

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());


                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    //Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", "");
                    //Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                    finish();
                    //startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }


}
```

JSONParser

```
package com.example.testemysql;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.d("Acha o erro POR FAVOR ajuda",""+ httpResponse);

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
            Log.d("Acha Erro POR FAVOR",""+ reader.readLine());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.d("Acha Erro", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e);
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser fallha", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**PHP - UPDATED**

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");

//gets user's info based off of a username.
$query = " 
        SELECT 
            indice, 
            usuario, 
            senha
        FROM usuarios 
        WHERE 
            usuario = :username 
    ";

$query_params = array(
    ':username' => $_POST["username"]
);

try {   
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    print_r (var_dump($_POST));
    print_r(get_headers());

    }
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!2";
    echo "Bruno 2";
    die(json_encode($response&$ex));

}

//This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's information is correct.
//we initialize it as false.
$validated_info = false;

//fetching all the rows from the query
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just
    //compare the two passwords
    if ($_POST["password"] === $row["senha"]) {
        $login_ok = true;
    }
}

// If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
// Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
if ($login_ok) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
    die(json_encode($response));
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}?>
```

**RESULTS**

```
09-16 16:58:00.687: D/Acha o erro POR FAVOR ajuda(29176):org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@42680990
09-16 16:58:00.687: D/Acha Erro POR FAVOR(29176): Array
09-16 16:58:00.687: D/Acha Erro(29176): (
09-16 16:58:00.687: D/Acha Erro(29176): )
09-16 16:58:00.687: D/Acha Erro(29176): array(0) {
09-16 16:58:00.687: D/Acha Erro(29176): }
09-16 16:58:00.687: D/Acha Erro(29176): {"success":0,"message":"Invalid Credentials!"}
```

Comment: Whats the rule to the parameter name? has it to be equals to the table field?

Comment: After thousand of tests, i´ve found out the problem, i just dont know how to solve it. The app is not posting de vars "username" and  "password" on php page. i found in other topics about type-content stuff, but didnt work for me. Any ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, i got a solution, the problem wasnt the code it was the server (6te.net) settings. I tried in a local xampp server and it worked fine.

Thanks to every body, especialy to greenapps.

Answer (score 1):

In your request, you should specify that the desired return is of type Json.

You may need to add something similar to the following to your HTTP Request Header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

In your code, I'd recommend something like this:

```
// defaultHttpClient
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type: application/json")
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: i tied it, but still the same, is there some way to do in the php page?

Comment: If you just log exactly what the POST returns, what do you get?

Comment: I got the same log adding the header. All my html on it.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your issue is in your filtering, never ever ever do string comparisons with ==, it doesn't work.

instead of doing this line:

```
if(method == "POST"){
//...
else if(method == "GET")
```

do this:

```
if (method.equals("POST"))
//...
else if(method.equals("GET"))
```

this is causing your post value to be sent to the server empty. thats the only reason your php script will ever output the login form instead of processing the JSON request... of course after you get past this issue, there may be other bugs to look into..

Comment: well, i tried, but still the same.I do agree that no postting action is happening is there some way to check it?

Comment: add more logging in the code to see the code flow, or run it in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You get the inlog page. So aparently you have to use a username and pass before your request is honored. With the browser you first logged in?

Ok i see in the php script that that html is returned when $_POST is empty. So you should POST better.

Comment: That´s exactly what i thought but, i dont know how i suport do that. What´s the best to do that?

Comment: You are already calling the send function with "POST". So at the moment i dont know why it goes wrong.

Comment: `if (!empty($_POST))` ? Change that to `if (isset($_POST))` for a try.

Comment: could  'String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");'`be the issue? utf-8 stuff?

Comment: Just make a much simpler php script first. Without database access and so. Just first echo the parameters like username and pass. Inspect the POST, GET and REQUEST array. You can dump them with simple php commands.

Comment: `Log.d("Acha o erro POR FAVOR ajuda",""+ httpResponse);` you did not tell if you see this log.

Comment: i´ve made the changes but, when i try for the browser it goes straight to the json, doesnt allow me to set the user and password. But in the apps now it got the json corretly, then the problem is problably about the post.

Comment: about Log.d you ask, i got 09-12 17:27:40.017: D/Acha o erro POR FAVOR ajuda(17120): org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@42670f38

Comment: i´ve made the changes, now my php is "if (isset($_POST))", then when i try in the browser it shows me the json with the post answer , I´m not getting the fist screen with user and password. But looking in the logcat, the app is getting corretly the json, so the problem is the post. The app is not posting.

Comment: But earlier you said that using your browser all was ok. So i'm more interested in what your app does now. Mmmmmm ??? If the app gets correctly the json then why would thete still be a problem in the post? I cannot follow you.

Comment: Yes, it was, but when i made the changes that u said, it got in this way. U said "if (!empty($_POST)) ? Change that to if (isset($_POST)) for a try."

Comment: I´ll do what u said, I´ll make a simpler php, just to return what i´ve typed.

Comment: I wonder why this class does not work for you. I've seen it used many times. And apart from @Dave's remarks it should work.

Comment: I´ve tried a simpler php, I could confirm, the problem is in the post action, the app is not posting. Any idea? 

`<?php
  if(!empty($_POST)){
  
  echo "FOI";
  }else{?>
    <h1>Teste</h1> 
  <form action="login_2.php" method="post"> 
      Username:<br /> 
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
      <br /><br /> 
      Password:<br /> 
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 
      <br /><br /> 
      <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
  </form> 
   <?php
   }
  ?>
  
 `

Comment: What is it doing instead? Which info did you get in php ? Where are your ideas? What did you all try? Have you used `echo file_get_contents( 'php://input' );` to echo all wat the script received back? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136253/how-to-print-all-information-from-an-http-request-to-the-screen-in-php Please do not post code in a comment block as it is unreadable. Post it in a code block.

Comment: After thousand of tests, i´ve found out the problem, i just dont know how to solve it. The app is not posting de vars "username" and  "password" on php page. i found in other topics about type-content stuff, but didnt work for me. Any ideia?

Comment: So the app is posting but not posting usename and pass? What does it post then? Please show a decent php script that dumps POST, GET and REQUEST parameters like described in the link i gave you. And post the result here. The `tried a simpler script` is pretty useless as it will not return any info.

Comment: Right, i added the  `print_r($_REQUEST);` and `print_r (var_dump($_HTTP_REQUEST));`, the first one i got blank and second one NULL, its in my logcat, when i tried in the browser i got `Array ( [PHPSESSID] => fjae41fm4g1as753bpoubrd3s4 ) NULL {"success":0,"message":"Invalid Credentials!"}`

Comment: Post the complete php script in a post block here (not in a comment). Post in another post block the response. That's the contents of String json. How could you try the script with a browser? Make another script in which only `echo file_get_contents( 'php://input' );` and post the contents of String json again.

Comment: Man, i posted a update in the php code here and the result in the logcat, i´m doing the file_get_contents now.

Comment: I had to search for the arraydump statements. My god you added them to that database script. The intention is that you make a complete new small script with only those lines. Just dump. And you forgot the GET array.

Comment: I got some news, the problem isnt in any part of the code, i created a xampp server and tested it, worked nice, the php returned the posted vars, but this very code doenst work on my online web service. What could i check to find out the problem?